Godot 4 Scenes randomly corrupting on launch
Whenever I launch my Godot 4 project, some specific scenes in my game will corrupt themselves, such that whenever I try to open the scene it displays a popup with the text:
Scene file 'scene.tscn' appears to be invalid/corrupt.
In the console this error message is also displayed upon attempting to open the scene in the editor.
 Failed to instantiate scene state of "scene.tscn", node count is 0. Make sure the PackedScene resource is valid.
I am not sure what is causing this, it will happen without me changing the scene at all, just opening and closing the editor. Most importantly, the project still runs perfectly fine, I am able to see the scenes within my game running normally when I test it, while the files are supposedly corrupted.
This is an example of what one of the corrupted scene files looks like:
[gd_scene load_steps=2 format=3 uid="uid://wenmbpbqeikr"]

[ext_resource type="Script" path="res://Creatures/CreatureBody.gd" id="1_2l5r3"]

[node name="CreatureBody" type="Node2D"]
script = ExtResource("1_2l5r3")

[node name="Shapes" type="Node2D" parent="."]

[node name="Legs" type="Node2D" parent="."]

[node name="Camera" type="Camera2D" parent="."]

So far the only consistent fix I have for this issue is to delete the scene and create a new identical one from scratch, however this is becoming tedious.
I have tried restarting the project, sometimes it fixes it but more often than not the scene remains corrupted.
I have tried deleting the .godot folder, making the project rebuild itself, and then seeing if the new built scene is not corrupted, but this also does not work. any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Make sure you don't have a cyclic reference of preload statements.

I think this might be the issue! In my scenes I usually include a static constructor function for instantiating the scenes. for example the scene I gave above includes the line const creature_body_scene = preload("res://Creatures/creature_body.tscn"), for the function static func make_creature_body(  creature_data: CreatureData,   position: Vector2=Vector2(0,0),   has_camera: bool=true ):  var new_creature = creature_body_scene.instantiate()  new_creature.creature_data = creature_data  new_creature.get_child(2).enabled = has_camera  return new_creature.

@CherryDT Nearly all of my scenes have this pattern however and only some of them frequently corrupt. do you think this could be fixed by turning the preload statements into load statements inside of the static constructor method? Or would this have the same issue?

I had a very similar issue ( and stream of related issues ). I went on the Godot Forums and got some advice that helped me solve the issue. I hope it helps :)
